# "no matching call" compiler error when using boost::signal

Tags: c++, boost-signals

In file A.hpp, I have

```
extern boost::signal<void (model::Bullet&, Point&, Point&, int)> signal_createBullet;
```

and so in file A.cpp, I have

```
boost::signal<void (model::Bullet&, Point&, Point&, int)> signal_createBullet;
```

In file B.hpp, I have a class `Entities` that has a static member function `receiveSignalCreateBullet` that I want to connect with `signal_createBullet`, like so: (namespaces omitted for brevity)

```
class Entities
{
    Entities()
    {
        signal_createBullet.connect(&receiveSignalCreateBullet);
    }

    public:
        static void receiveSignalCreateBullet(const Bullet&, const Point&, const Point&, const int);
};

inline static void receiveSignalCreateBullet(...) { ... }
```

and finally in file C.cpp, I use `signal_createBullet` like this:

```
signal_createBullet(bullet, pos, bulletVector, count);
```

A and B compile successfully (using g++), but C fails with this error message:

```
In member function ‘virtual void thrl::model::SingleStream::shoot(const thrl::utl::Point&, const   thrl::utl::Point&, const thrl::utl::Point&) const’:
src/Shot.cpp:25: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::signal4<void, thrl::model::Bullet&,  thrl::utl::Point&, thrl::utl::Point&, int, boost::last_value<void>, int, std::less<int>,   boost::function4<void, thrl::model::Bullet&, thrl::utl::Point&, thrl::utl::Point&, int> >) (const   thrl::model::Bullet&, const thrl::utl::Point&, thrl::utl::Point&, int&)’
/usr/local/include/boost/signals/signal_template.hpp:330: note: candidates are: typename   boost::signal4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4, Combiner, Group, GroupCompare, SlotFunction>::result_type   boost::signal4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4, Combiner, Group, GroupCompare, SlotFunction>::operator()(T1, T2, T3, T4)   [with R = void, T1 = thrl::model::Bullet&, T2 = thrl::utl::Point&, T3 = thrl::utl::Point&, T4 = int,   Combiner = boost::last_value<void>, Group = int, GroupCompare = std::less<int>, SlotFunction =   boost::function4<void, thrl::model::Bullet&, thrl::utl::Point&, thrl::utl::Point&, int>]
/usr/local/include/boost/signals/signal_template.hpp:370: note:                 typename   boost::signal4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4, Combiner, Group, GroupCompare, SlotFunction>::result_type   boost::signal4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4, Combiner, Group, GroupCompare, SlotFunction>::operator()(T1, T2, T3, T4)   const [with R = void, T1 = thrl::model::Bullet&, T2 = thrl::utl::Point&, T3 = thrl::utl::Point&, T4   = int, Combiner = boost::last_value<void>, Group = int, GroupCompare = std::less<int>, SlotFunction =   boost::function4<void, thrl::model::Bullet&, thrl::utl::Point&, thrl::utl::Point&, int>]
```

While trying to figure this out, I formatted my call and the first candidate in the error message to more easily compare them:

```
// my call
‘(
    boost::signal
    <
        void
        (
            thrl::model::Bullet&, 
            thrl::utl::Point&, 
            thrl::utl::Point&, 
            int
        ), 
        boost::last_value<void>, 
        int, 
        std::less<int>, 
        boost::function
        <
            void
            (
                thrl::model::Bullet&, 
                thrl::utl::Point&, 
                thrl::utl::Point&, 
                int
            )
        > 
    >
) 
(
    const thrl::model::Bullet&, 
    const thrl::utl::Point&, 
    thrl::utl::Point&, 
    int&
)’

// what g++ expects
typename boost::signal4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4, Combiner, Group, GroupCompare, SlotFunction>::result_type 
    boost::signal4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4, Combiner, Group, GroupCompare, SlotFunction>::operator()(T1, T2, T3, T4) 
    [ with
        R  = void, 
        T1 = thrl::model::Bullet&, 
        T2 = thrl::utl::Point&, 
        T3 = thrl::utl::Point&, 
        T4 = int, 
        Combiner = boost::last_value<void>, 
        Group = int, 
        GroupCompare = std::less<int>, 
        SlotFunction = boost::function
        <
            void
            (
                thrl::model::Bullet&, 
                thrl::utl::Point&, 
                thrl::utl::Point&, 
                int
            )
        >
    ]
// the second candidate is the same as the first, except that it's const
```

Besides the fact that the candidate uses the 'Portable' syntax, (and no, switching my code to use the Portable style makes no difference) I see no difference between the two calls except that the last thing in my call is `int&` where the candidate has a `int`.  I tried removing the `int` parameter from the signal to see if that was the problem, and it wasn't.

Anyone see why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> static void receiveSignalCreateBullet(const Bullet&, const Point&, const Point&, const int);

Why parameters here are const? In signal declaration they are not const.

Comment: Aagh!  They were originally const, and while I was fanagling my code trying to get things to work, I made them not const, and forgot to change them back.  Thanks for spying the obvious for me. :)